# NGINX & Consul-Template in Docker

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, docker, consul

I'm having trouble with consistent service discovery using EC2, AWS, Docker, Consul-Template, Consul, and NGINX.

I have multiple services, each running on it's own EC2 instance. On these instances I run the following containers (in this order):

- cAdvisor (monitoring)
- node-exporter (monitoring)
- Consul (running in agent mode)
- Registrator
- My service
- Custom container running both nginx and consul-template

The custom container has the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.9

#Install Curl
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y install curl

#Install Consul Template
RUN curl -L https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template/releases/download/v0.10.0/consul-template_0.10.0_linux_amd64.tar.gz | tar -C /usr/local/bin --strip-components 1 -zxf -

#Setup Consul Template Files
RUN mkdir /etc/consul-templates
COPY ./app.conf.tmpl /etc/consul-templates/app.conf

# Remove all other conf files from nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*

#Default Variables
ENV CONSUL consul:8500

CMD /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && consul-template -consul=$CONSUL -template "/etc/consul-templates/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf:/usr/sbin/nginx -s reload"
```

The app.conf file looks like this:

```
{{range services}}
  upstream {{.Name}} {
    least_conn;{{range service .Name}}
    server {{.Address}}:{{.Port}};{{end}}
  }
{{end}}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  proxy_set_header            Host $host;
  proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://cart/cart/;
  }

  location /cart {
    proxy_pass http://cart/cart;
  }

  {{range services}}
  location /api/{{.Name}} {
    proxy_read_timeout 180;
    proxy_pass http://{{.Name}}/{{.Name}};
  }
  {{end}}
}
```

Everything seems to start up perfectly ok, but at some point (which I'm yet to identify) after start up, consul-template seems to return that there are no available servers for a particular service. This means that the `upstream` section for that service contains no servers, and I end up with this in the logs:

```
2015/12/04 07:09:34 [emerg] 77#77: no servers are inside upstream in /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf:336
nginx: [emerg] no servers are inside upstream in /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf:336
2015/12/04 07:09:34 [ERR] (runner) error running command: exit status 1
Consul Template returned errors:
1 error(s) occurred:

* exit status 1
2015/12/04 07:09:34 [DEBUG] (logging) setting up logging
2015/12/04 07:09:34 [DEBUG] (logging) config:

{
  "name": "consul-template",
  "level": "WARN",
  "syslog": false,
  "syslog_facility": "LOCAL0"
}

2015/12/04 07:09:34 [emerg] 7#7: no servers are inside upstream in /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf:336
nginx: [emerg] no servers are inside upstream in /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf:336
```

After this, NGINX will no longer accept requests.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I've tied myself in mental knots about the sequence of events etc. What I think might be happening is that NGINX crashes, but because consul-template is still running, the Docker container doesn't restart. I don't actually care if the container itself restarts, or if just NGINX restarts.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consul Template will exit once the script it runs after writing  returns a non-zero exit code. [See here for the documentation.](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template#termination-on-error)

The documentation suggests to put a `|| true` just after the restart (or reload) command. This will keep Consul Template running independent of the exit code.

You could consider wrapping the restart in its own shell script that first tests the configuration (with `nginx -t`) before triggering a reload. You could even move the initial start of nginx to this script as it only makes sense to start `nginx` once the first (valid) configuration has been written?!

Comment: So does ````-t```` effectively do a validation check on the configuration it's being asked to reload, and if the validation fails, it refuses to do a reload? If so, that might help.

Comment: `-t` will only validate the configuration. `reload` will first test the configuration and if successful reload the configuration - see https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/.

Comment: Ok, so if I add the || true, that'll stop consul-template from exiting, and thus presumably keep the container running. However, if Nginx has crashed/exited, then reload will have no effect, correct? Or, is it that the reload command is returning 1, whilst Nginx continues to run, but consul-template has exited?

Comment: As I understand it only the reload command returned 1. The nginx process itself continued to run.

Comment: Awesome. I'll give that a crack today and get back to you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Adding ````|| true```` seems to have fixed it. That's awesome. Thanks @ahus1!!